# Rails 3 Authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authorization, roles, has-many-through, cancan

I am trying to figure out how I can perform authorization on my Rails 3 application. I was using CanCan, but I needed to get a little more complex than one user role.

My application has a User Model, Project Model and a Project Members Model. There is a Has Many Through relationship setup between those models. Below is the current schema....

**Users**
- First Name
- Last Name
- Email

**Projects**
- Name
- active

**Project Members**
- user_id
- project_id
- role

When a user logs into the site they are prompted to select a project from a select menu. The options in the select menu are created from

> current_users.departments.where(:active
>   => true)

After they hit submit a session variable is set for session[:department_id]. What I need to find is a way to pull the role id for the user and project and lock down certain things based on the that role.

Thanks,
Kyle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to take care of this with CanCan and with the help of Ryan B.